# Turning off my phone when power is disconnected

Tags: rooting, tasker, systemless-root

I am using Tasker to do some scheduling tasks and it is working all flawlessly. Now there is one thing where I am stuck at. 
I want to turn airplan mode on and power off my phone whenever the charging turns off. For this, tasker needs the device to be rooted.

Can you guys please suggest me what are the minimal steps I need to take to make this happen (minimal modification to the system) At this point of time I dont want to use the other amazing features which rooting provides but just powering off my device and turning airplane mode on using tasker / MacroDroid.

I have two samsung tablets on which I want to make this happen. One is Samsung Tab S4 and the other one is Samsung Tab A 10.5.

Comment: Which Android versions do these devices have?

Comment: @Firelord both of these have Android Pie.